# What does “sh a.sh <&0 >&0” mean?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

`sh a.sh <&0 >&0` -- what does it mean? 
In particular, I'm not very clear about what `&0` means.

Answer (score 13):

`n>&p` and `n<&p` are the same operator and are for duplicating the file descriptor (fd) `p` onto the file descriptor `n`. Or said otherwise, they redirect the file descriptor `n` to whatever resource fd `p` is redirected to.

The `<` and `>` are not used to determine what direction (reading or writing) the redirected file descriptor will be used. `n` will get the same direction as `p`. That is, if `p` was open for writing, so will be `n` even if the `n<&p` operator is used.

The only difference between the two operators is when `n` is not specified. `>&p` redirects stdout (is like `1>&p` or `1<&p`) and `<&p` redirects stdin (is like `0<&p` or `0>&p`).

So `<&0` is like `0<&0`, so redirects stdin to whatever resource stdin was redirected to, so does nothing useful, it's usually a no-op and doesn't make much sense.

But not always a no-op, not in every shell. When job control is disabled, POSIX requires stdin of command in the background to be redirected to `/dev/null` or an equivalent file. In Bash (tested in 4.4.12) `<&0` overrides this. Compare `(ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 &)` and `(<&0 ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 &)`. In some cases this is useful.

`>&0` duplicates the fd 0 onto the fd 1. Because the fd 1 (stdout), is by convention only used for writing, that `>&0` only makes sense if fd 0 was open in read+write mode.

That would be the case in cases where fd 0 points to the terminal device, because terminal emulators or `getty` would generally open the terminal device in read+write mode and assign fds 0, 1 and 2 to it.

So maybe whoever wrote that wanted to redirect stdout to the terminal assuming that stdin was pointing to it.

One place where `n>&n` makes sense is with zsh and its `mult_IOs` feature. In `zsh`:

```
some-cmd >&1 > some-file
# that is: some-cmd 1>&1 1> some-file
```

Redirects the standard output of `some-cmd` to both whatever stdout was before (&1) and `some-file`, as if you had written:

```
some-cmd | tee some-file
```

While

```
some-cmd <&0 < some-file
# that is: some-cmd 0<&0 0< some-file
```

would feed first the original stdin and then `some-file` as input to `some-cmd` as if you had written:

```
cat - some-file | some-cmd
```

But in `cmd <&0 >&0`, fd 0 is redirected only once, so that does not apply.

`n>&n` can also have an interesting side effect in some shells (`ksh`, `zsh`, not `dash`, `bash` nor `yash`) in that it triggers an error and gives up running the command if the file descriptor `n` is not open. So, in those shells,

```
cmd 0<&0
```

would avoid running `cmd` in the pathological condition where `stdin` is closed:

```
$ ksh -c 'cat file - <&0' <&-
ksh: 0: cannot open [Bad file descriptor]
$ mksh -c 'cat file - <&0' <&-
mksh: <&0 : bad file descriptor
$ zsh -c 'cat file - <&0' <&-
zsh:1: 0: bad file descriptor

$ bash -c 'cat file - <&0' <&-
contents of file
cat: -: Bad file descriptor
cat: closing standard input: Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 4):

& followed by a digit in that case indicates a file number.  File number 0 is standard input (`stdin`).  The `<` and `>` characters indicate redirection of the process's standard in and standard out respectively.

So, in short, this command means to run `a.sh` in `sh` (as a shell script), redirecting both the script's (really, the subshell's) standard in and out to standard in.

In this case, `<&0` is redundant (this is the default behaviour).  `>&0` will mean it prints what would otherwise be printed on standard out to standard in instead, relative to the parent shell.  Most ttys will echo such output, and so in consequence the redirection has almost no effect and probably no visible effect.

One case this would be reasonable is if the parent shell's standard output file were strangely closed.  This is a strange edge case.

Comment: The standard term is *file descriptor.*